# Adding PHP In Article

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, articles, extensions

I am wanting to connect to a SQL Server Instance in my article, and I have the below syntax to do such.  My issue is that when I view the article it writes

> ".$row['book_name']."
>   "; } ?>

onto the screen instead of interpreting it as part of the code.  This is the code that I have, what do I need to alter so that the Joomla Article interprets this properly?

```
<?php
//provide your hostname, username and dbname
$host=""; 
$username="";  
$password="";
$db_name=""; 
//$con=mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
$con=mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password");
mysql_select_db("$db_name");
$book_name = $_POST['book_name'];
$sql = "select book_name from book_mast where book_name LIKE '$book_name%'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<p>".$row['book_name']."</p>";
}
?>
```

**EDIT**
Updated to use JFactory

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select($db->quoteName(array('Top 1 employer')));
$query->from($db->quoteName('#[Roster].[dbo].[Employers]')); 
$db->setQuery($query); 
$row = $db->loadRow();
print_r($row);
```

But how do I pass in the server and credentials in this set-up?

**EDIT 2**
I have updated my code to use the `JDatabaseDriver` since my Joomla Install and the server I want to query are on different instances.  I added in this syntax:

```
    <?php
    $option = array(); //prevent problems

    $option['driver']   = 'mysql';            // Database driver name
    $option['host']     = 'db.myhost.com';    // Database host name
    $option['user']     = 'fredbloggs';       // User for database authentication
    $option['password'] = 's9(39s£h[%dkFd';   // Password for database authentication
    $option['database'] = 'bigdatabase';      // Database name
    $option['prefix']   = 'abc_';             // Database prefix (may be empty)

    $db = JDatabaseDriver::getInstance( $option );
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query->select($db->quoteName(array('Top 1 employer')));
    $query->from($db->quoteName('#[Roster].[dbo].[Employers]')); 
    $db->setQuery($query); 
    $row = $db->loadRow();
    print_r($row);
?>
```

And now I get displayed on screen on page load everything after

> getQuery(true);

What am I missing here?

Comment: Firstly, don't use `mysql_*` as it's deprecated. Secondly, use the JDatabase class to connect to your database. Joomla has wrappers for a reason, so please use them. Have a read of the doucmentation: http://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase

Comment: How do I pass in host, username, password, dbname using JDatabase?

Comment: Is the table you want to get the data from the same database your Joomla site uses?

Comment: No.  My Joomla site exists on a MySQL server, I am wanting to query a MSSQL server instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to use this plugin here Regular Labs [**Sourcerer**](https://www.regularlabs.com/extensions/sourcerer).

Took this from the description of the plugin page:

> Sourcerer enables you to place PHP and any kind of HTML style code
>   (including CSS and JavaScript) right into your content! Not only in
>   your articles, but also in sections, categories, modules, components,
>   META tags, etc.
>
> You can now just place your original codes right into your WYSIWYG
>   editor. The only thing you have to do is surround the code with the
>   Sourcerer tags. Easy peasy!
>
> So now you can also use PHP scripts in your content. That opens up a
>   great deal of possibilities.
>
> Most Joomla! Text Editors will strip parts of your HTML code, like
>   JavaScripts (think of statistics scripts) and movie embed tags. With
>   Sourcerer you won't have these limitations.