# PHP Table Not Showing In Article

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-3.5

If I click the Preview button in my article, it displays the table exactly as I thought I had set-up.  However, if I try to click through and get the page to display on the front-end, no table is shown.  What is causing Joomla to not show the table?

```
<?php

    $param1 = $_GET['param1'];
    $param2 = $_GET['param2'];
    $param3 = $_GET['param3'];

    $server = "Server"; 
        $uid = "uid"; 
        $pwd = "pwd"; 
        $database = "DB"; 

    $conn = mssql_connect($server,$uid,$pwd);

    if ($conn===false)
    {
        echo '<p>Cannot connect to SQL Server Database. Please try again later.</p>';
        exit;
    }
    if (mssql_select_db($database,$conn) === false) 
    {
        echo '<p>Cannot connect to DB. Please try again later.</p>';
        exit;
    }
    $proc = mssql_init('ProcedureName',$conn);
    mssql_bind($proc,'@param1',$param1,SQLVARCHAR);
    mssql_bind($proc,'@param2',$param2,SQLVARCHAR);
    mssql_bind($proc,'@param3',$param3,SQLVARCHAR);
    if ($result = mssql_execute($proc)) 
    {
        $number_of_rows = mssql_num_rows($result);
        if($number_of_rows > 0) {
            echo '<table border="1">';
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '  <th>Employee </th>';
            echo '  <th>EmployeeID </th>';
            echo '  <th>Sale Price </th>';
            echo '  <th>Tax Price </th>';
            echo '  <th>Total Price </th>';
            echo '  <th>Market Price </th>';
            echo '</tr>';  

        while ($Row = mssql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
        {
            echo '<tr><td>'.$Row['Employee'] . 
            '</td><td>'.$Row['EmployeeID'] . 
            '</td><td>'."$".round($Row['SalePrice']) . 
            '</td><td>'."$".round($Row['TaxPrice']) . 
            '</td><td>'."$".round($Row['TotalPrice']) . 
            '</td><td>'."$".round($Row['MarketPrice']) . 
            '</td></tr>';
        }
            echo '</table>';
        }
        mssql_close($con);
    }
?>
```

Comment: ln 26, you have a typo.its `mysql` not `mssql`

Comment: I am using mssql, not mysql.  This syntax returns the results as needed, it just does not create the table.

Comment: Have you checked CSS in front-end? It's not unusal for `table` selector to be heavily modified by template.css.

Comment: Are you writing php directly inside the article? Check here: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/19193/adding-php-in-article

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see anything wrong with the echos, if the editor does not remove your code, i would suggest to remove one by one the following ifs to see if it is echoing the table headers no matter the query results

```
if ($result = mssql_execute($proc)) {
if($number_of_rows > 0) {
```

Also make sure you get at least one result from the query by changing all the table data code with something like this

```
while ($Row = mssql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $Row['Employee'];
}
```

**UPDATE:**

If you place your code strait in the article it wont work try using an extension like [Regular Labs - Sourcerer](https://www.regularlabs.com/extensions/sourcerer) and place your code inside the

> {source} your code {/source}

then give it a try

Comment: I removed both if statements, but the table is still not being displayed.  Interesting thing about it, I have the same syntax in an external php file that populates a div tag in the article and it creates the table perfectly.  However, when running the syntax in the article itself it does not create the table.

Comment: @IcyPopTarts the table is not showing but if you inspect the source code using your Browser Inspector, is the code for the table there?

Comment: @Lodder - if I right click the page and say view source, the content is placed in a `div` tag and has no table structure.

Answer (score 0):

You should not add php to the articles, also your code is very dangerous, you are using params without any escaping and filtering.

Comment: How should the code be setup?

Comment: You should use JInput https://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput and specify appropriate filters, right now you are open to varios hacking attack as you use no filtering for values you are getting from URL - you use them directly in the query